# Excel Interop C# - How to read individual cell characters

Tags: c#, excel, parameters, properties, interop

I would like to convert the Excel cell content to html (including font color, size, etc.) only with `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` (Microsoft 365 64 bits / .NET  7.0) and no external libraries.

I manage to get all characters via `range.Characters`, but I'm not able to get individual character. I understand that from the documentation, it can't be iterated through, but it seems possible to get any sub-characters via [Range.Characters[Object, Object] Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.characters?view=excel-pia) which perfectly works from VBA.

Does anyone have an idea what cause the issue? Why am I not able to write `range.Characters[1, 1]` to get the first character?

PS I already encountered a few methods (such as `Add()` instead of `AddEx()` for the `ListRows` which are highlighted via the intellisence, but I don't think it corresponds to a similar issue since we are facing a property but not a method).

Comment: I'm curious, why are you trying to do this? There may be a better way to achieve whatever it is you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Basically, I don't intend to use Excel for my application in the future anymore. For the time being I use Excel to write and update the data (about 20 tables) and transfer them to a SQL Server (I already wrote many CRUD lines). I would like to have some columns with advanced text formatting (still need to figure out how to convert them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell you why (perhaps someone with better knowledge of the dlls will know), but I can say that you can call the methods and properties of the `Characters` object. For example, if you're trying to access the character, the syntax `rng.Characters[1, 1].Text` will yield the string.

I presume that you're trying to access the `Characters` object to change a font or something on single character.

The sample code below gives some examples:

```
        var app = new XL.Application
        {
            Visible = true
        };
        var wb = app.Workbooks.Add();
        var ws = (XL.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
        var rng = ws.Range["A1"];

        Console.WriteLine("Range value = abc");
        rng.Value = "abc";

        Console.WriteLine("Reading each character...");
        for (var i = 1; i <= rng.Characters.Count; i++)
        {
            var c = rng.Characters[i, 1].Text;
            Console.WriteLine($"  Character {i} = {c}");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Setting second charater to x");
        rng.Characters[2, 1].Text = "x";
        Console.WriteLine($"Range value = {rng.Characters.Text}");

        Console.WriteLine("Making second charater bold");
        rng.Characters[2, 1].Font.Bold = true;

        Console.WriteLine("See Excel app for range value change.");
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close Excel app.");
        Console.ReadKey();
        wb.Close(false);
        app.Quit();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've just realised that using `dynamic` instead of `var` doesn't show an error... but leads to the `System.MissingMemberException: 'Error while invoking [PROPERTYGET, DISPID(0)].'` exception.

Comment: You can assign anything to a variable of type `dynamic` (it's like `object` in this regard). But, problems with `dynamic` will only manifest themselves at runtime, as you've found